# Can't change class when using getElementsByClass

Tags: javascript, css

I've been going around in circles on this one. I have a PHP output that generates a series of DIV elements, and each has a class of L1, L2, L3, etc. These classes have a CSS that's basically blank so they display by default.

The problem is trying to change the class of each DIV to hide it, based on a simple onclick function. I'm using document.getElementsByClass to get (for example) just the DIV CLASS="L1" elements. But when I try to change the class, either with setAttribute('class', 'L1hide') or with className = "L1hide", nothing happens.

I know the HTML/CSS portion works, since I altered the PHP to generate "L1hide" instead of just "L1" and saw that the DIV CLASS="L1hide" elements were indeed hidden.

Is it because I'm trying to both grab the class and change the class at the same time? All the examples I see use getElementById, but this isn't practical for me since ID must be unique. I have zero, one, or more L1/L2/etc. class elements.

Here are some HTML code output by PHP:

```
<div class="L1"><h3>Owner</h3>
<table>
  <tr><td>Jim Smith</td></tr>
</table>
</div>

<div class="L1"><h3>Executives</h3>
<table>
  <tr><td>Harry Atkins</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Galen Singh</td></tr>
</table>
</div>

<div class="L2"><h3>Managers</h3>
<table>
  <tr><td>Andy Jones</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Mary Thompson</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Bill Murphy</td></tr>
</table>
</div>
```

And here is some javascript. This should change the image and hide the L1's. The image change DOES work (first 4 lines), but the style won't change (last 2 lines) despite my burnt offerings:

```
managmentImage.onclick = function() {
  if (managmentLevel == "TOP1.png") {
    document.getElementById("managementImage").setAttribute("src", "TOP0.png");
    managmentLevel = "TOP0.png";
    document.getElementsByClassName("L1").className = "L1hide";
    divL1 = "L1hide";
} else { ...
```

Note: There is basically duplicate "else" code to change the image back, and to re-display the L1's. I only provided the first half of the "if" statement since the solution would also apply to the remaining "else" portion.

Comment: which browser do you test on?

Comment: It is an HTML Collection is NOT like getElementById

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getElementsByClass` is returning an array-like collection of nodes; those don't have `className`, individual nodes do.

You can't iterate it normally, because it is a live collection: if you change the class of the first element, the array shortens by one, so you will only process half of the nodes if you iterate from start to end. Iterating from end to start fixes this issue.

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("L1");
console.log(elements);
var i = elements.length;
while (i--) {
  elements[i].className = "L1hide";
}
```

```css
.L1hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="L1"><h3>Owner</h3>
<table>
  <tr><td>Jim Smith</td></tr>
</table>
</div>

<div class="L1"><h3>Executives</h3>
<table>
  <tr><td>Harry Atkins</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Galen Singh</td></tr>
</table>
</div>

<div class="L2"><h3>Managers</h3>
<table>
  <tr><td>Andy Jones</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Mary Thompson</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Bill Murphy</td></tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: That was perfect! Thank you, very much.

Answer (score 1):

getElementByClassName() returns an array.
You must iterate on it and then change the property.

Comment: Not *quite* an array.